# Serilog reference cannot add in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, serilog

I am new in asp.net core and want to make a sample project to clear my concepts. I want to make a logger using Serilog in asp.net core but I am facing a problem in adding reference of serilog in project.json file.

It shows an error :

> The dependency Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer does not support
>   framework.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0

I google a lot but no solution found and still searching for it. How can I add it in reference?

Below is a screenshot :

[image]

All dependencies :

[[image]]

Comment: Can you please share your project.json?

Comment: Bro Plz see my post again, I edit it. @Sanket

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Serilog member *nblumhardt* on this github [issue](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver/issues/47) - They holding off for .NET Core 2.0 before moving this sink (Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer).

Workaround at this moment is to use **Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServerCore** instead of Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer. Refer below links-

- Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServerCore: https://github.com/aaxelm/serilog-sinks-mssqlservercore
- Published at: https://www.nuget.org/packages/serilog.sinks.mssqlservercore